# Comparing Machine learning algorithms performance to predict the likelihood surviving Titanic

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to understand a [guide](https://www.kaggle.com/ldfreeman3/a-data-science-framework-to-achieve-99-accuracy/notebook) about a ML model to predict the likelihood someone surviving sinking Titanic.

I'm stuck on cell 21. It's basically trying to compare the performance of 21 different ML algorithms after splitting data. So the end result would be something like the following:

[Expected result  cell 21, if run correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNiYu.png)

Cell 21:

```
# Machine Learning Algorithm (MLA) Selection and Initialization
MLA = [
    # Ensemble Methods
    ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier(), 
    ensemble.BaggingClassifier(),
    ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier(), 
    ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier(), 
    ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(), 
    
    # Gaussian Processes
    gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier(), 
    
    # GLM
    linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(), 
    linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier(), 
    linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV(),
    linear_model.SGDClassifier(),
    linear_model.Perceptron(),
    
    # Navies Bayes
    naive_bayes.BernoulliNB(),
    naive_bayes.GaussianNB(),
    
    # Nearest Neighbor
    neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
    
    # SVM
    svm.SVC(probability = True), 
    svm.NuSVC(probability = True), 
    svm.LinearSVC(), 
    
    # Trees
    tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    tree.ExtraTreeClassifier(),
    
    # Discriminant Analysis
    discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
    discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(),
    
    # xgboost
    XGBClassifier()
]

# Split dataset in cross-validation with this splitter class
# note: this is an alternative to train_test_split
cv_split = model_selection.ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = .3, train_size = .6, random_state = 0)
# run model 10x with split 60/30 split intentionally leaving 10%

# Create table to compare MLA metrics
MLA_columns = ['MLA Name', 'MLA Parameters', 'MLA Train Accuracy Mean', 'MLA Test Accuracy Mean', 
               'MLA Test Accuracy 3*STD', 'MLA Time']
MLA_compare = pd.DataFrame(columns = MLA_columns)

# Create table to compare MLA predictions
MLA_predict = data1[Target]

# Index through MLA and save performance to table
row_index = 0
for alg in MLA:
    # set name and parameters
    MLA_name = alg.__class__.__name__
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Name'] = MLA_name
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Parameters'] = str(alg.get_params())
    
    # score model with cross validation
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(alg, data1[data1_x_bin], data1[Target], cv = cv_split)
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Time'] = cv_results['fit_time'].mean()
    print(cv_results.keys())
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Train Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['train_score'].mean()
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['test_score'].mean()
    
    # If this is a non-bias random sample, then +/-3 standard deviations (std) from the mean, should statistically
    # capture 99.7% of the subsets.
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy 3*STD'] = cv_results['test_score'].std()*3
    # Let's know the worst that can happen!
    
    # Save MLA predictions
    alg.fit(data1[data1_x_bin], data1[Target])
    MLA_predict[MLA_name] = alg.predict(data1[data1_x_bin])
    
    row_index+=1

# Print and sort table
MLA_compare.sort_values(by = ['MLA Test Accuracy Mean'], ascending = False, inplace = True)
MLA_compare
# MLA_predict
```

After running it, I get the following error:

```
dict_keys(['fit_time', 'score_time', 'test_score'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-cbe9dc24e1e0> in <module>
     67     MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Time'] = cv_results['fit_time'].mean()
     68     print(cv_results.keys())
---> 69     MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Train Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['train_score'].mean()
     70     MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['test_score'].mean()
     71 

KeyError: 'train_score'
```

As you can see, 'train_score' doesn't even exist as `cv_results.keys()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` documentation for `train_score` column to be returned you need to specify `return_train_score` as `true` like this:

```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(alg, data1[data1_x_bin], data1[Target], cv = cv_split, return_train_score=True)
```